# How can I aggregate metrics per day in a Grafana table?

Tags: grafana

I am charting data with a Grafana table, and I want to aggregate all data points from a single day into one row in the table. As you can see below my current setup is displaying the values on a per / minute basis.

[image: Grafana Table]

**Question:** How can I make a Grafana table that displays values aggregated by day?

```
|        Day        | ReCaptcha  | T & C |
|-------------------|------------|-------|
| February 21, 2017 |   9,001    | 8,999 |
| February 20, 2017 |      42    |    17 |
| February 19, 2017 |     ...    |   ... |
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the summarize function on the metrics panel. 
Change the query by pressing the + then selecting transform
summarize(24h, sum, false) this will aggregate the past 24hr data points into a single point by summing them.

http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEHb3.png)

Comment: This is working great, thank you. For those interested in the exact query I ended up with

`alias(summarize(sumSeries(my_giant_query.count), '24hr', 'sum', false), 'ReCaptcha')`

_**Note:**_ `sumSeries` used to aggregate data from multiple servers

Comment: 24 hours rolling is not the same as current day