# Grafana SNMP traffic accounting, is it possible?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Please bear with me, I am getting my feet wet with Grafana/Telegraf/InfluxDB.

I succeeded following tutorials to poll a router via snmp and have its traffic graphed. Nice!

Now, I need a table containing traffic per time frame, especially daily. Something like this:

```
|        Day        | ifHCInOctets  | ifHCOutOctets | Total    |
|-------------------|---------------|---------------|----------|
| February 21, 2017 |         xy GB |         xy GB |    xy GB |
| February 20, 2017 |         xy GB |         xy GB |    xy GB |
| February 19, 2017 |         xy GB |         xy GB |    xy GB |
```

I have seen the advice in [How can I aggregate metrics per day in a Grafana table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374268/how-can-i-aggregate-metrics-per-day-in-a-grafana-table), but the web editor can't be fed with it(?).

Thank you for reading.

Edit: Thank you for your comment, which is greatly appreciated. In fact, my values *are* cumulative counters, just like they are polled via SNMP. I was mostly following the tutorial at https://lkhill.com/telegraf-influx-grafana-network-stats/.

So, my task at hand seems to be to generate a sane database, and record data deltas (counter rollover also has to be taken in account, right?). How could I accomplish this? My Google-Fu is failing me greatly.

The result SHOW TAG KEYS & SHOW FIELD KEYS is as follows:

```
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.4.2
InfluxDB shell version: 1.4.2

SHOW TAG KEYS;


name: cpu
tagKey
------
cpu
host

name: disk
tagKey
------
device
fstype
host
mode
path

name: diskio
tagKey
------
host
name

name: interface
tagKey
------
agent_host
dot3StatsIndex
host
hostname
ifDescr
ifIndex

name: kernel
tagKey
------
host

name: mem
tagKey
------
host

name: processes
tagKey
------
host

name: snmp
tagKey
------
agent_host
host
hostname
ifName

name: swap
tagKey
------
host

name: system
tagKey
------
host



SHOW FIELD KEYS;
name: cpu
fieldKey         fieldType
--------         ---------
usage_guest      float
usage_guest_nice float
usage_idle       float
usage_iowait     float
usage_irq        float
usage_nice       float
usage_softirq    float
usage_steal      float
usage_system     float
usage_user       float

name: disk
fieldKey     fieldType
--------     ---------
free         integer
inodes_free  integer
inodes_total integer
inodes_used  integer
total        integer
used         integer
used_percent float

name: diskio
fieldKey         fieldType
--------         ---------
io_time          integer
iops_in_progress integer
read_bytes       integer
read_time        integer
reads            integer
weighted_io_time integer
write_bytes      integer
write_time       integer
writes           integer

name: interface
fieldKey                           fieldType
--------                           ---------
dot3StatsAlignmentErrors           integer
dot3StatsCarrierSenseErrors        integer
dot3StatsDeferredTransmissions     integer
dot3StatsDuplexStatus              integer
dot3StatsEtherChipSet              string
dot3StatsExcessiveCollisions       integer
dot3StatsFCSErrors                 integer
dot3StatsFrameTooLongs             integer
dot3StatsInternalMacReceiveErrors  integer
dot3StatsInternalMacTransmitErrors integer
dot3StatsLateCollisions            integer
dot3StatsMultipleCollisionFrames   integer
dot3StatsSQETestErrors             integer
dot3StatsSingleCollisionFrames     integer
dot3StatsSymbolErrors              integer
ifAdminStatus                      integer
ifAlias                            string
ifConnectorPresent                 integer
ifCounterDiscontinuityTime         integer
ifDescr                            string
ifHCInBroadcastPkts                integer
ifHCInMulticastPkts                integer
ifHCInOctets                       integer
ifHCInUcastPkts                    integer
ifHCOutBroadcastPkts               integer
ifHCOutMulticastPkts               integer
ifHCOutOctets                      integer
ifHCOutUcastPkts                   integer
ifHighSpeed                        integer
ifInBroadcastPkts                  integer
ifInDiscards                       integer
ifInErrors                         integer
ifInMulticastPkts                  integer
ifInOctets                         integer
ifInUcastPkts                      integer
ifInUnknownProtos                  integer
ifLastChange                       integer
ifLinkUpDownTrapEnable             integer
ifMtu                              integer
ifName                             string
ifOperStatus                       integer
ifOutBroadcastPkts                 integer
ifOutDiscards                      integer
ifOutErrors                        integer
ifOutMulticastPkts                 integer
ifOutOctets                        integer
ifOutUcastPkts                     integer
ifPhysAddress                      string
ifPromiscuousMode                  integer
ifSpeed                            integer
ifType                             integer

name: kernel
fieldKey         fieldType
--------         ---------
boot_time        integer
context_switches integer
interrupts       integer
processes_forked integer

name: mem
fieldKey          fieldType
--------          ---------
active            integer
available         integer
available_percent float
buffered          integer
cached            integer
free              integer
inactive          integer
slab              integer
total             integer
used              integer
used_percent      float

name: processes
fieldKey      fieldType
--------      ---------
blocked       integer
dead          integer
idle          integer
paging        integer
running       integer
sleeping      integer
stopped       integer
total         integer
total_threads integer
unknown       integer
zombies       integer

name: snmp
fieldKey                   fieldType
--------                   ---------
ifAlias                    string
ifConnectorPresent         integer
ifCounterDiscontinuityTime integer
ifHCInBroadcastPkts        integer
ifHCInMulticastPkts        integer
ifHCInOctets               integer
ifHCInUcastPkts            integer
ifHCOutBroadcastPkts       integer
ifHCOutMulticastPkts       integer
ifHCOutOctets              integer
ifHCOutUcastPkts           integer
ifHighSpeed                integer
ifInBroadcastPkts          integer
ifInMulticastPkts          integer
ifLinkUpDownTrapEnable     integer
ifName                     string
ifOutBroadcastPkts         integer
ifOutMulticastPkts         integer
ifPromiscuousMode          integer
uptime                     integer

name: swap
fieldKey     fieldType
--------     ---------
free         integer
in           integer
out          integer
total        integer
used         integer
used_percent float

name: system
fieldKey      fieldType
--------      ---------
load1         float
load15        float
load5         float
n_cpus        integer
n_users       integer
uptime        integer
uptime_format string
```

Comment: Show your metrics, first. Add (at least) the results of SHOW TAG KEYS & SHOW FIELD KEYS for desired measurements. That would help.

Answer (score 0):

The generic method: you simply sum (or aggregate another way) your values by time period.
That should look pretty familiar (I'm assuming, values of your metric shows the delta, the amount of traffic that gone through since the previous measurement, NOT a cumulative counter):

```
SELECT sum("ifHCInOctets") FROM "YourMeasurement" WHERE time > now() - 10d GROUP BY time(1d)
```

In Grafana, it's gonna be looking like

```
SELECT sum("ifHCInOctets") FROM "YourMeasurement" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval)
```

Just don't forget to configure your interval explicitly.

Though if you just add more details about your measurements, it's going to be easier for you to obtain more precise advice.

UPDATE:
So, it is cumulative.
Fine.

Then here's the thing: you can have your deltas with `DIFFERENCE()` between series grouped by time period. And in case of the cumulative counters - obviously, you need only the last value in the series.

Although, here's two things.

**First**: it looks like you don't have the overall counter, but rather couple of counters per some group(s).

Looking at your schema (tags, particularly) I can presume it's host-based (and, perhaps, interfaces are to be considered as well). Thus, you should add grouping by host, otherwise `DIFFERENCE()` would yield utter nonsense, because value would be taken only by timestamp, with no regard what counter is that.

**Second**... I got no idea if the counters could be reset throughout the period you're interested in.

But if they could - I don't really know yet how to handle it (except with Kapacitor).

It's kind of ok if you aim to have a sequence of deltas per period to be shown as throughput - you'd know that sudden "deep into the negs and back" peeks were counters' reset.

But if you intend to further aggregate this (like, sum this deltas through the day) - it would impact that value.

So, it's gonna look something like

```
SELECT DIFFERENCE(LAST("ifHCInOctets")) FROM "YourMeasurement" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY host, ifName, time($interval)
```

That's gonna be your throughput per period in `$interval`.

Comment: Thanks(!), I edited my post to add more information.

Comment: Oopsy... that's a bit to much to show, I didn't expect you won't narrow it with FROM "snmp" (and/or "interface" if you like). You can clean up all except that, it's kinda messy now.